# How can I use PERIOD in the htaccess link?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've tried to create a link like this: website.com/profile/name 
**from:** website.com/profile.php?name=Name

Everything works fine, except when I use a name with a dot in it. So for example: website.com/profile/Alex.
This wouldn't work, and would just remove the dot from the link. So basically it wouldn't display that DOT in php.

This is my htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /alliance/404.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.php - [F,L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)$ ./profile.php?name=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([^/.]+)` means any chars except `.` and `/` so this does not match `alex.` . If you want your rule to accept `.` in uri, change your rule's pattern to the following :

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ ./profile.php?name=$1
```